# What is the CSS class of this text? (picture attached)

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

In Lightning, in the Opportunity related list of an Account, this is what I see:

[image]

I am creating my own component and I want to style my **reference to an Opportunity** (the blue text) just like it is done in the standard Account layout.

In particular, I want to know what I should do to:

1. Get the font size right. It is not body_small or heading_small, but something in between.
2. Get the permanent subtle underline. I cannot find any styling element that can do that.

Comment: Have you tried right-click>Inspect to see what its classes are?

Comment: Yes I have. There is some textUnderline and h3 involved, but so far I have not been able to accomplish the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dots are created by

```
a[force-hoverableLink_hoverableLink] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And the size is defined in

```
.slds-form-element__static {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: var(--lwc-inputStaticFontSize,0.875rem);
    font-weight: var(--lwc-inputStaticFontWeight,400);
    color: var(--lwc-inputStaticColor,rgb(8, 7, 7));
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The size is right now, after I applied <div class="slds-form-element__static"> But what do I need to do with the hoverable link part? What do I put where? I know a bit about CSS, but I am no expert.

Comment: I cannot put the a[...] in the css file, as that gives me the error: Invalid usage of attribute selector "force-hoverableLink_hoverableLink". "force-hoverableLink_hoverableLink" is a template directive and therefore not supported in css rules

Comment: In my HTML I used the <lightning-formatted-url> tag. I replaced it by an <a> tag and in my CSS I put a:link {
 border-bottom: 1px dotted;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
} And now it's perfect.